# Neukirch's papers and theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, translation, anabelian-geometry

Have any of Neukirch's papers on anabelian geometry been translated? I'm mostly interested in:

[Kennzeichnung der p-adischen und der endlichen algebraischen Zahlkörper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0244211) (1969)

[Kennzeichnung der endlich-algebraischen Zahlkörper durch die Galoisgruppe der maximal auflösbaren Erweiterungen](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0258804) (1969)

Alternatively, any exposition of Neukirch's part of the proof of Neukirch–Uchida theorem (Uchida's paper is available in english), this is, number fields with the same absolute Galois group are isomorphic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find this in the last chapter of [Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg, Cohomology of Number Fields], http://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/NSW2e/index-de.html.

See also [Ivanov, On a generalization of the Neukirch-Uchida theorem, arXiv:1309.3046,  2013] http://www-m11.ma.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bnb/www/people/ivanov/Neukirch_Uchida_stable_01.pdf